# TypeScript - passing props to a Redux-connected component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a Redux-connected component that has these types: (partial code)

```
export interface OwnProps {
 age: number;
}
...
...
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>
(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

But when i try to render it with passing the `age` prop:

```
<MyComponent age={10} />
```

I'm getting the TS error:

```
Type '{ age: number }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ....
```

The full version of the error above essentially says that my type is missing 10 properties, all of them are essentially the `StateProps` properties of this component.

**EDIT:**

I have my `mapStateToProps` set to:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState): StateProps => ({ ... });
```

And i soon as i added `ApplicationState` to my `connect`, the error disappeared:

```
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps, ApplicationState>
(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

But why?